# How do I step into other class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

This is really testing "there's no such thing as a stupid question"

Here is the `console` code:

```
class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        myClass cl = new myClass();
        cl.myMethod("world");

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class myClass {

    public void myMethod(string x) {
        Console.WriteLine("hello {0}", x);
    }
}
```

If I press `F10` and step into `Main` and then keep pressing `F10` why does it not step into `myClass` ?

Can I change my settings so it steps into other called classes?

Comment: Because you need to press F11? F10 = Step Over, F11 = Step Into

Comment: ....dear dear - it was doing exactly as it says on the tin; classic user fail !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The F11 option will work (right way to step into). 
You can also set breakpoint in the class you want to step into and that will also work.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F11</kbd> is your solution. It's for stepping in.

Answer (score 1):

Because <kbd>F11</kbd> is Step *Into*, <kbd>F10</kbd> is Step *Over*.

Note that <kbd>F11</kbd> can still *seem* to step over in certain circumstances, namely when working with properties and you've OKd Visual Studio to 'ignore' stepping into the body.

Answer (score 1):

This is, somewhat, a real test :)

Press F11 instead of F10. Read more about debugging in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QCPt9aOcd98) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528302/debugging-how-do-i-execute-code-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0):

The `F10` is the *step over* command, it doesn't step into methods that are called.

Use `F11` to get the *step into* command, that does step into methods.

Answer (score 0):

According to [hotkeys list](http://www.dofactory.com/ShortCutKeys/ShortCutKeys.aspx) the <kbd>F10</kbd> does not step into. What you want is the <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

`F10`: Step Over

`F11`: Step Into

`Shift+F11`: Step Out