# C# SQL database check

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am writing a C# program, and so far I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqConsoleApp
{
    [Table(Name = "DesanoDict1")]
    public class DesanoDict1
    {
        private string _Desano;
        [Column(Storage = "_Desano")]
        public string Desano
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private string _Portuguese;
        [Column(Storage = "_Portuguese")]
        public string Portuguese
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private string _English;
        [Column(Storage = "_English")]
        public string English
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private string _Spanish;
        [Column(Storage = "_Spanish")]
        public string Spanish
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Use a connection string.
            DataContext db = new DataContext
                (@"C:\Users\FieldLingLab\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GUI Test\GUI Test\Resources\Desano\Desano.mdf");
            Table<DesanoDict1> dd1 = db.GetTable<DesanoDict1>();

            IQueryable<DesanoDict1> DesQuery = from des in dd1 select des;

            foreach(DesanoDict1 dd in DesQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Desano={0}, Portuguese={1}. English={2}, Spanish={3}", dd.Desano, dd.Portuguese, dd.English, dd.Spanish);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that nothing is written to the console, so either the database is not being connected to, or a table isn't created properly, or something relating to those. I am not sure how to test to see what's wrong, considering I can't write any contents of `dd1` or `db` to the console, only their types. How do I check these?

Comment: You can try to [debug your app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/debug-your-app-vs).

Comment: Does `DataContext` just accept a file path like that? I am not sure if it does or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use Visual Studio [step debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) to execute the code line by line and use Inspector to see the values of the variables.

Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528302/debugging-how-do-i-execute-code-line-by-line).