# Visual Studio new form won't open, no errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

So I have this existing code where I want to add a new form (generated), which is opened from a toolstrip menu.

In the main form, I've added

```
using NsPeak;

(...)     

public void peakToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form fPeak = new FormPeak(this);
            fPeak.Show();
        }
```

and in the new form FormPeak.cs

```
namespace NsPeak
{

    public partial class FormPeak : Form
    {
        public FormPeak(gui.Form1 f1)
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }
```

When running the code or debugging, I see the menu entry, I can click it, but then the menu simply closes with no new form appearing.
I get zero errors or warnings during compilation.

Any ideas how to debug this? What could be wrong or missing?

Thank you in advance and best wishes,
Irmi

Comment: Use [step-by-step debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528302/debugging-how-do-i-execute-code-line-by-line)

Comment: Specify `fPeak.Width` and `fPeak.Height`, also it might be opening off screen so set the `.Top` and `.Left` to `0`

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your `peakToolStripMenuItem_Click()` event handler and made sure its called at all?

Comment: Have you verified that the `peakToolStripMenuItem_Click` eventhandler has been wired to the click of the button in the menu? If so, set a breakpoint in the eventhandler method body and verify that the code to show the form is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your comment, Lars Kristensen!
This solved it for me.

There is a corresponding "click"-entry in the properties -> events -> action menu of the toolstripmenu design, where the handler should be selected.

beginners error - sorry guys!